# Why does my Framework expose pure Swift `enum` as a `non-closed enum`, requiring usage of `@unknown default`?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, enums, frameworks

I have a dynamic framework the compilation of which I configure completely via Xcode. It uses some Objective-C code so it has a bridging header.

I have a public enum:

```swift
public enum Foo {
    case bar
    case baz
}
```

As you can see, it's a pure Swift enum.

However, once I compile the framework and import the compiled framework, I get a warning about `@unknown default` handling when I use instances of this enum. I don't expect this, because it's a Swift enum - it's supposed to be equivalent to `NS_CLOSED_ENUM`.

```
Switch covers known cases, but 'Foo' may have additional unknown values
Handle unknown values using "@unknown default"
```

When I take a peek into the `.swiftinterface` of my Framework, I find this:

```swift
public enum Foo {
  case bar
  case baz
  public static func == (a: SDK.Foo, b: SDK.Foo) -> Swift.Bool
  public func hash(into hasher: inout Swift.Hasher)
  public var hashValue: Swift.Int {
    get
  }
}
```

It's all declared properly, all good, which makes me think that because it's a sovereign pre-compiled framework that is linked dynamically, Swift assumes that somehow on runtime a different version of it may be present which will suddenly have more enum cases. But is never going to happen because this framework will be supplied with the app and there definitely won't be new cases, and if there is, the framework user will get compilation errors!

How do I tell Swift "no, this is a framework that will be bundled, no cases are unknown!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`frozen` keyword is the answer - I marked `Foo` as `frozen` and it worked.

```swift
@frozen enum Foo {
    case bar
    case baz
}
```